# Why does the bottom of my Wordpress page get cut off in IE (but not Firefox)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress-theming

I'm using a WordPress design for [www.williamcoit.com](http://www.williamcoit.com/). My site shows all the content on [the Services page](http://williamcoit.com/services) in Firefox, but it cuts off at Local Services in Internet Explorer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post a link of your work.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: IE 7  www.williamcoit.com/services is the page

Comment: do you have to copy to content directly from word?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has happened because you pasted the content in directly from Microsoft Word.

Content pasted in from Word often contains *special code* which is designed only for Internet Explorer.

Ironically, in this case, IE is the only browser in which it's *not working*.

You ***really, really*** need to get rid of all the redundant markup from Word. Your page is 633KB, which is huge compared to the size it should be.

However, I did find a "fix" to make most of the content appear in IE.

You need to do a global find and replace in the HTML source of that page:

**Find:** `--><!--[endif]-->`
**Replace:** `<![endif]-->`

That makes most of the text visible in IE.